# Pulseaudio failing to set profiles and not detecting devices

Tags: udev, pulseaudio

For some time now, I have been having a problem with Pulseaudio. Pulseaudio sometimes gives my devices the wrong profiles and sometimes doesn't detect some of them at all. Because of that I decided to add the following lines to my `/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules`:

```
DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0", ENV{PULSE_NAME}="IntelSoundCard"
DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1", ENV{PULSE_NAME}="NvidiaSoundCard"
DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/sound/card3", ENV{PULSE_NAME}="BlueYetiNano"
DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/sound/card2", ENV{PULSE_NAME}="A4Tech"
```

And the following to my `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
set-card-profile alsa_card.BlueYetiNano    input:iec958-stereo
set-card-profile alsa_card.A4Tech           input:iec958-stereo
set-card-profile alsa_card.NvidiaSoundCard output:hdmi-stereo-extra1
set-card-profile alsa_card.IntelSoundCard  output:analog-stereo
```

As I've came to understand this, this should make the names of my devices static and Pulseaudio should based on these set the profiles I wish it to use.

The problem is that with the added lines to my `/etc/pulse/default.pa` Pulseaudio crashes on boot and gives the following error:

```
Sep 23 15:45:26 Simon-s-PC pulseaudio[10162]: No card found by this name or index.
Sep 23 15:45:26 Simon-s-PC pulseaudio[10162]: Failed to initialize daemon due to errors while executing startup commands. Source of commands: /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

So it seems that, the names aren't set correctly or the devices aren't detected. And that is indeed the case, if after boot I remove these lines and start Pulseaudio, Pulseaudio doesn't auto-detect some devices. It also seems that the `DEVPATH` used in `/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules` can change.

Because of these errors I suspect I don't understand this correctly. I guess the question is: Do I understand this correctly? What am I missing? How to do this, how do I set my profiles statically without Pulseaudio crashing?

Here is some hopefully useful stuff:

- [/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules](https://paste.debian.net/1164453/)
- [/etc/pulse/default.pa](https://paste.debian.net/1164454/)
- [pacmd list-cards (when all devices are detected)](https://paste.debian.net/1164455/)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've managed to get the device names (`PULSE_NAME`) to get set statically using `udev` rules. The thing is I was using `DEVPATH`, which can change. It makes perfect sense for the USB devices, other devices don't have static `DEVPATH` either. The solution is to use other attributes, for example `id` this way: `ATTR{id}=="Nano", ENV{PULSE_NAME}="BlueYetiNano"`. You can find these by using this command: `info -a --path=<DEVPATH>`. The problem although seems to persist. Pulseaudio crashes with the same error on boot even tough the names are correct.

Comment: I've found a workaround. I added `StartLimitBurst=60` to `/etc/systemd/user/default.target.wants/pulseaudio.service`. This allows `pulseaudio` to restart 60 times while starting if it fails.

Comment: pulseaudio (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11) seems to have some problem detecting devices. Which version do you use?

Comment: Sorry for a super late response... I am on `PulseAudio `15.0` and `libpipewire` `0.3.39`. I seem to be running into a similar issue again. PipeWire seems to not detect all devices on startup sometimes and I have to restart it to get them to show up. Profiles are also sometimes missing