# PipeWire not detecting devices and profiles

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, pipewire

I am having issues with `PipeWire`, on startup, it seems to not detect devices and their profiles. I sometimes have to do the following to get everything working. Though this does not happen always and sometimes different devices/profiles are missing.

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire
killall plasmashell && plasmashell& # this doesn't seem to be necessary anymore
```

This probably has a relation to [my other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611070/pulseaudio-failing-to-set-profiles-and-not-detecting-devices) which seems to have resurfaced in this form with my system starting to use `PipeWire`.

---

The logs are saying the following:

```
> journalctl --user -u pipewire
Nov 14 08:53:08 Simon-s-PC systemd[1131]: Started PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Nov 14 08:53:08 Simon-s-PC pipewire[1444]: mod.rtkit: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Nov 14 08:53:08 Simon-s-PC pipewire[1444]: mod.rtkit: could not set nice-level to -11: Permission denied
Nov 14 08:53:09 Simon-s-PC pipewire[1444]: mod.rtkit: RTKit error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied
Nov 14 08:53:09 Simon-s-PC pipewire[1444]: mod.rtkit: could not make thread realtime: Permission denied
Nov 14 08:53:10 Simon-s-PC pipewire[1444]: spa.alsa: 'front:2': capture open failed: Device or resource busy
Nov 14 08:53:10 Simon-s-PC pipewire[1444]: mod.adapter: 0x5630be589270: can't get format: Device or resource busy
Nov 14 08:53:10 Simon-s-PC pipewire[1444]: mod.adapter: can't create node: Device or resource busy
```

And some version/system info:

```
❯ pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 15.0
❯ pipewire --version
pipewire
Compiled with libpipewire 0.3.39
Linked with libpipewire 0.3.39
❯ uname -a
Linux Simon-s-PC 5.10.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.4-1 (2020-12-31) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The issue seems have magically fixed itself, no idea why

Comment: Apparently, it just happens more rarely but it happens

Comment: I'm having a similar issue after a Debian update.

Comment: why do you have a pulseaudio binary? Do you have the pulseaudio service active? the pulseaudio.service and pulseaudio.socket units must be disabled